# I want my JTable to be the same size of my linkedlist

Tags: java, swing

```
    String[] columns = new String[] {"Name", "Position", "Salary"};
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
        {employeelist.get(0), employeepost.get(0), employeesal.get(0)},
        {employeelist.get(1), employeepost.get(1), employeesal.get(1)},
        {employeelist.get(2), employeepost.get(2), employeesal.get(2)},
        {employeelist.get(3), employeepost.get(3), employeesal.get(3)},





    };
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
    b.add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

I want it to adjust to the same size of the linkedlist? and input my linkedlist in it in order.[image]

This is what i want it to be. but it expands as i add more employees.
sorry for bad english

Comment: *"This is what i want it to be. but it expands as i add more employees"* By which you mean?  Shouldn't it expand as you add more employees?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that extends [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html). This class will override at least 3 methods. In method [`getRowCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getRowCount--) you need to return the size of your array / list.

In [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) you will find examples how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 jta.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(jta.getPreferredSize());
 jta.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

Comment: No need for the first line, as this will make the `JScrollPane` the same size as the table, which is kind of pointless, especially if you have 100's of rows and the window flows of the screen :P